# При нажатии на submit не происходит перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, jquery, submit

Начал догадываться, что это из-за того, что на странице `submit` изначально не лежал, по этому и не случаеться событие. Но всё же решил спросить, как это лучше сделать? Или какое решение можете подсказать. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

```js
 $(function(){
      $('#banPlayer').click(function(){
        $('#adminPanel').html(''+
          'Дать бан игроку:<br>'+
          '<input class="pnlTBtn" name="login" placeholder="Логин" required type="text" maxlength="25"><br><br>'+
          'На срок:<br>'+
          '<input class="pnlTBtn" name="days" placeholder="дней" required type="text" maxlength="25">дней'+
          '<input class="std-submit" name="day_sub" value="Забанить" type="submit"><br>'+
          'или<br>'+
          '<input class="pnlTBtn" name="minutes" placeholder="минут" required type="text" maxlength="25">минут'+
          '<input class="std-submit" name="min_sub" value="Забанить" type="submit">'
        );
      });
      
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="banPlayer">В Баню</button>
<div id="adminPanel"></div>
```

Comment: А почему она должна перезагружаться-то? Здесь же нет `<form>` и браузер не знает что отправлять

Answer (score 1):

Элементы **<input>** должны быть заключены в тег **<form>**.

```
 $(function(){
  $('#banPlayer').click(function(){
    $('#adminPanel').html(''+
      'Дать бан игроку:<br>'+
      '<form action="">'+
      '<input class="pnlTBtn" name="login" placeholder="Логин" required type="text" maxlength="25"><br><br>'+
      'На срок:<br>'+
      '<input class="pnlTBtn" name="days" placeholder="дней" required type="text" maxlength="25">дней'+
      '<input class="std-submit" name="day_sub" value="Забанить" type="submit"><br>'+
      'или<br>'+
      '<input class="pnlTBtn" name="minutes" placeholder="минут" required type="text" maxlength="25">минут'+
      '<input class="std-submit" name="min_sub" value="Забанить" type="submit">'+
      '</form>'
    );
  });

});
```

**UPDATE.** При условии, конечно, что тэга form уже не существует в обрамляющем коде